# Datatable Object Not Available inside Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, dropbox-api

I'm using jQuery and the [Datatables plugin](http://datatables.net) to draw a table. The data I'm using comes from the Dropbox Datastore API. I think this question is more about JavaScript variable scope than about Datatables or Dropbox, so hopefully someone can help.

Here's my code. The comments describe each step.

```
$(function(){

  //Authenticate dropbox
  client.authenticate({interactive: false}, function(error) {
    // Get aircraft data from dropbox
    var aircraftData = [];

    function getAircraftData(){
      aircraftData.push(...);
    }
    getAircraftData();

    //Initialize Aircraft table
    var aircraftTable = $('#aircraft-table').DataTable({
      data:aircraftData,
      ...
    }); 
    console.log(aircraftTable); //This yields a generic [object Object]

    //Incoming data changes from Dropbox listener
    datastore.recordsChanged.addListener(function (event) {
      //Update aircraftData[]
      getAircraftData();

      //Refresh the datatable
      aircraftTable.draw(); // -!- ERROR: undefined is not a function -!-
      console.log(aircraftTable); //This also yields a generic [object Object]
    });
  });
});
```

I'm guessing `aircraftTable` isn't available because it's out of scope when inside the Dropbox listener function. How do I bring it in scope so it's available?

**Update**

I tweaked my code to show some additional context. All of this is happening inside another Dropbox function. Normally when you log a `DataTable` object to the console, it looks something like this:

```
[context: Array[1], selector: Object, tables: function, table: function, draw: function…]
```

The table works fine, but somehow referencing it isn't working.

Comment: What version of datatables are you using? The `.draw` function is only available since 1.10 [(according to this documentation)](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29)

Comment: I'm on version 1.10.4

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally figured this out.

First of all, when I was logging things to the console, I was prepending the object with some kind of description like this:

```
console.log('Aircraft table: '+aircraftTable);
```

...which logged `[object Object]`. But if you want to see an object and its properties, you can't concatenate it with a string. You have to just do:

```
console.log(aircraftTable);
```

So it turns out the `aircraftTable` was in fact available, but I was using the wrong methods on it. Here is the correct way to grab new data and redraw the table:

```
//Refresh table                
var aircraftData = getAircraftData();                
aircraftTable.clear().rows.add(aircraftData).draw();
```

Here are the docs for `rows.add()`: http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()

What a relief. :)

Comment: DUDE! Thank you so much. I've been searching for two days for a solution. We didn't really have the exact same problem, but your solution got me where I needed to be.